# Why does " TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int' " pop up?

Tags: python, string, int, command-line-arguments, median

Why does " TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int' " pop up and how could I fix it?

**CODE:**

```
import sys
import statistics
list_num = sys.argv[1:]
print(list_num)
for i in range(0, len(list_num)): 
    if list_num[i].isdigit():
        list_num[i] = str(list_num[i])
    else:
        list_num[i] = str(len(list_num[i]))
print(list_num)
print("Mode: " + str(statistics.mode(list_num)))
print("Median: " + str(statistics.median(list_num)))
```

**OUTPUT:**

> ['1', '2', 'way', 'fdk', '4', 'fdsfdsds']
>   ['1', '2', '3', '3', '4', '8']
>   Mode: 3
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "main.py", line 12, in 
>       print("Median: " + str(statistics.median(list_num)))
>     File "/usr/lib/python3.4/statistics.py", line 318, in median
>       return (data[i - 1] + data[i])/2
>   TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to do a calculation with strings. Don't convert the items in the list to strings before calculating the median

```
import sys
import statistics
list_num = sys.argv[1:]
print(list_num)
for i in range(0, len(list_num)): 
    if list_num[i].isdigit():
        list_num[i] = float(list_num[i])
    else:
        list_num[i] = float(len(list_num[i]))
print(list_num)
print("Mode:", str(statistics.mode(list_num)))
print("Median:", str(statistics.median(list_num)))
```

I've changed the str() functions for [float()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_float.asp) functions. You can also use [int()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_int.asp), depending on what you want to achieve.

Moreover, you are converting the outcome of the mode and median functions to a string. A string is text, and not a number. Are you sure this is what you want to do?

Comment: Thank you so much! :) Ye, I messed there most definitely.

Comment: Glad I could help! Please don't forget to accept my answer by clicking the check icon below the downvote button (:

Answer (score -1):

The array list_num you have as argument should be composed by numbers, ints or floats. You have a list of strings: ['1', '2', '3', '3', '4', '8']. It should be: [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 8], without single quotes.